# Replace function $$find always returns nothing

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

I have a QT project file (.pro), and would like to add some compiler specific flags.

Rather than typing out `if win32-msvc2013|win32-msvc2010|...` for every version of MSVC, I thought I could just search for the substring "msvc".

I did some research and found the [find](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-function-reference.html#find-variablename-substr) function, which seems perfect for the job.

To test this, I added `message($$find($$QMAKESPEC, "*msvc*"))` to the project file. However, it always prints blank, regardless of whether or not the `$$QMAKESPEC` variable contains the substring "msvc". I've also tried `message($$find($$QMAKESPEC, "msvc"))`, `message($$find($$QMAKESPEC, msvc))` and `message($$find($$QMAKESPEC, *msvc*))`.

I checked the value of `$$QMAKESPEC` with `message($$QMAKESPEC)`, and it printed `E:/Qt/5.4/msvc2013_64/mkspecs/win32-msvc2013`.

How can I use the find function to check for a substring in a variable in a QT project file?

#### Update

[Frank Osterfeld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/299399/frank-osterfeld) suggested using `msvc { ... }` in the comments, which works great! However I feel this question is still useful as `$$find` still isn't working as expected.

---

#### Version Info

Qt Creator 3.3.2 (opensource)
Based on Qt 5.4.1 (MSVC 2010, 32 bit)

Built on Mar 4 2015 at 00:09:05

From revision 3af3fe7ad3

Comment: Have you tried `msvc: something` in your .pro file?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld ah that works great thanks :) Although it doesn't explain why ``$$find`` doesn't work

Comment: You need to pass the function name, not its content (i.e. QMAKESPEC, not $$QMAKESPEC). It might not do what you expect though. See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-function-reference.html Also note there's contains().

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld ah that did the trick, thanks. If you write this up in an answer, I'll accept

Comment: Or use "win32: something" instead of msvc, if you care about platform rather than compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are qmake methods that take a string and there are methods that take a variable.

Replace `$$find($$QMAKESPEC, "msvc")` by `$$find(QMAKESPEC, "msvc")`.

Testme

```
message("Test me")
message($$QMAKESPEC)
# MSVC
message($$find($$QMAKESPEC, "msvc"))
message($$find(QMAKESPEC, "msvc"))
# linux
message($$find($$QMAKESPEC, "linux"))
message($$find(QMAKESPEC, "linux"))
# g++ does not work because it is a regular expression
message($$find($$QMAKESPEC, "g++"))
message($$find(QMAKESPEC, "g++"))
# g\+\+ does work
message($$find($$QMAKESPEC, "g\+\+"))
message($$find(QMAKESPEC, "g\+\+"))
```